# When is the -ING form not used in the Present Perfect (Passive voice)

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice

Is using the present participle compulsory in the structure *have/has been*?

I once read a sentence

> The work **has been completed** flawlessly by her.

I understand that we use *have/has been* + *present participle* to express actions that went on in the past and were completed in the present.

I would like to know when I should use '*have/has been*' without the *present participle* (-ING form).

Comment: Please give some more details along with some examples of what you are asking about here so that this question can be reopened. See the [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for some help on how to provide more information, and why that is so important.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for your suggestuon.I edited my question :)

Comment: **has completed** is a normal construction for present perfect in active voice. **Has been completed** is a passive construction in passive voice. **Has been completing** is present perfect continuous.

Answer (score 1):

When you express *to be* in the past perfect, it's not followed by a present participle.  A noun or adjective will follow.

> I had been a police officer in the past.

Past perfect passive voice verbs are followed by a past participle, not a present participle.

> The pool had been drained by last Tuesday by the maintenance crew.